# How to create a Basic Jersey RESTful CRUD Example with Login/Authentication feature

Tags: rest, authentication, jersey, crud

okay so i have made the basic rest example and now i wanted to take it a step further by using authentication (user login) in my example.

I am only using Java Collection for my data. NO DATABASE !!

I am storeing the user data in a Map where email is the key to his password !!

But i am getting stuck at the basic authentication part where a form request is being posted to my rest -post method where it takes the values from the users...something like this:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,
        public void newUser(
        @FormParam("email") String email,
        @FormParam("password") String password,@ContextHttpServletResponse servletResponse
) throws IOException {

    // Form Processing algo
if(emailexists){
servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/xxx/LoginFailed.html");
  }
else{
    servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/xxx/UserHomPage.html");
  }    
}
```

Dont know what i am doing wrong ..
Also only Java Collections are to be used (like Lists,Map.etc).

Am i using the right technique here or anyone has got a better one at their disposel.

Any help would be appreciated !

I am on windows using apache tomcat 6..

AND A TOTAL NOOB AT THIS THING !!

Answer (score 0):

To save persistent data (like usernames and passwords) without a database, you should consider saving the data in a text file server side and reading the data back into a map in your constructor.

However, the more data you have the more expensive this process is. If you have a large number of users you really should consider using databases, because they are more organized, more efficient, and far more easy to use.

```
    @Path("myPath")
    public class MyResource {

        private static final String FILE_PATH="my/path/to/userdata.txt";

        private HashMap<String, String> _userData;

        public MyResource() {
            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(FILE_PATH));
                _userData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                    String[] line = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
                    _userData.put(line[0].trim(), line[1].trim());
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        public Response addNewUser(@FormParam("email") String email,
                                   @FormParam("password") String password)
                                   throws IOException {

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(FILE_PATH));
            int statusCode = 200;
            // If that email already exists, don't print to file
            if(_userData.containsKey(email))
                statusCode = 400;
            else
                writer.println(email + "," + password);
            writer.close();
            return Response.status(statusCode);
        }
    }
```